# Fork particular files from a repository in github

Tags: git, github

i'd like to fork only a couple of files from some repository. For these particular files I'd like to be able to track and merge the upstream changes.

Best Regards

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  The "fork" concept applies to repos, not files.  Are you trying to fork an entire repo, but only track upstream changes for some files?  Or do you want to only check out (and track) certain files, without getting the rest of the files?  Are you planning to edit these files, or do you just want local copies that track the ones in the remote repo?  Are you planning on editing the rest of the files, but aren't interested in upstream changes regarding those?  A little more information on what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish would be helpful. =)

Comment: I want to 're-use' some files from another repository (to extend them). However, I'd like to be able to re-integrate upstream fixes.

Comment: I see.  I don't think there's an easy way to do it, although I could be wrong.  With `.gitattributes` you can specify merge strategies for certain files, but as far as I can tell, you can't do that when merging a branch from a specific remote, automatically.  Off the top of my head, all I can think of is generating patches from the new commits from upstream, and applying those patches with `git apply --include=<path-pattern>`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although it's clunky (and I haven't tested it):

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git diff upstream/master -- file1.ext path/to/file2.ext yet/another/file3.ext | git apply -
$ git add file1.ext path/to/file2.ext yet/another/file3.ext
$ git commit
```

Where "upstream" is the name of the upstream remote, and "master" (as in "upstream/master") is the branch you're tracking.

Basically, you're saying "fetch the latest changes from upstream, make a patch of what's different between my current files and the upstream files, for a certain list of files, apply that patch, add the files to the index, and commit".

(The working tree should be clean, or else you'll be including changes not from upstream in your commit, which is not a problem but can be confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at sub-modules.  You may find after digging into it that the complexity isn't warranted.  It's likely better to just clone the entire repository and ignore the other files.